# Remove obsolete comments on badly formulated questions after they are improved?

Tags: discussion, comments

I noticed there are several questions on the main site with comments that the question isn't very good, then followed by comments of the author what he/she means. This usually goes one for a bit and then the question is edited and improved

Some examples (EDIT: most obsolete comments in the examples are now removed)

- [Is Buddhism a religion or a philosophy?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1584/408)
- [Are there any cultural or religious guidelines for Buddhist tattoos?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1789/408)
- [Plants may be sentient beings like animals so how do you decide what to eat?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/2152/408)
- [Relationship between Buddhism, Hinduism and Yoga?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/123/408)
- [How to help non-Buddhists understand a young person's desire to be ordained as a monk?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/137/408)

On most SE sites the policy is to remove those comments after the question is improved because they have little value. Do we want this here also? I.e. should we encourage the authors to remove the comments themselves and flag the ones that remain as 'obsolete'?

Comment: It does make it confusing for people reading later after the question has been improved to still have all those comments. Makes us look hypercritical. ;-)

Comment: FWIW unless there's something compelling that comes up in this meta discussion, I'll clean up the comments on these later. I'm leaving them for now as reference for this post.

Comment: Yes, comment clean up (removal) is good, especially when the Q makes the comments unintelligible (because their referents are gone)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm very pro cleaning up stale comments and have done so on a bunch of questions. The older comments–and their context–get deleted along with back-and-forth chats.

That said, I mostly only clean up such when I come across them. I normally don't actively go looking for them, so it is easy to miss them here and there.

Comment: Great! I just wanted to make sure before I start flagging several comments. BTW, I've added another example question and will continu to do so if I find more. That is, until you say you've cleaned the questions in the list.

Comment: Please do flag comments ^_^ I'm happy to take a look.